# Load ir.sequence into Odoo POS

Tags: odoo-10

I'm trying to load `ir.sequence` into **Odoo POS** because I need to print the `pos.order sequence`. But for some reason looks like the `load_models` is not being called. I've successfully added additional fields to already loaded models. this is my code. I'm using **odoo v11**.

```
var core = require('web.core');
var QWeb = core.qweb;
var _t = core._t;    

var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

models.load_fields('res.company', 'street');
models.load_fields('res.company', 'street2');
models.load_fields('res.company', 'city');

models.load_models([{        
    model: 'ir.sequence',
    condition: function(self){ return true; },
    fields: [],
    domain: function(self){ return [['code','=','pos.order']]; },          
    loaded: function(self, result){
        //self.set('secuencia', result[0].id);            
        self.secuencia = result;                   
    },        
}]);
```

I just realized that when I enable `developer mode with assets` it works but when i run without development mode is not loading. I'm inheriting the template like this:

```
<template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" 
                src="/ss_point_of_sale/static/src/js/ss_point_of_sale.js">
        </script>            
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Is there something else I have to do? maybe the script order?

Comment: Have you checked other inserted fields of res.company like street2,city are loading in your POS?

Comment: Hi, someone from the community helped me. Odoo does not like <script></script>. Just <script .... />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/ss_point_of_sale/static/src/js/ss_point_of_sale.js"/>
```

I closed the script tag and removed

```
</script>
```